# Delete draft mail on close when not sent

Tags: vba, email, outlook, mailmessage, mailitem

I've got some draft mails with some buttons to copy and open them. Only a few values need to be filled in and then the mails will be sent. I want to keep the drafts. But if a mail is not sent, I would like to delete it because it is a copy. I'm working with the close event for a mail item, but I can't seem to find out how to delete it in that sub, tried many things. Anyone knows how to approach this?

Code I got so far in a module:

```
Dim itmevt As New CMailItemEvents
Public olMail As Variant
Public olApp As Outlook.Application
Public olNs As NameSpace
Public Fldr As MAPIFolder


Sub TeamcenterWEBAccount()

Dim i As Integer
Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem

Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Fldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDrafts)

For Each olMail In Fldr.Items
    If InStr(olMail.Subject, "New account") <> 0 Then
        Set NewItem = olMail.Copy
        olMail.Display
        Set itmevt.itm = olMail
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next olMail

End Sub
```

Code in the CMailItemEvents class module:

```
Option Explicit
Public WithEvents itm As Outlook.MailItem

Private Sub itm_Close(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim blnSent As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    blnSent = itm.Sent
    If blnSent = False Then
        itm.DeleteAfterSubmit = True
    Else
       ' do
End Sub
```

Comment: So, you want showing specific mails (from Drafts) having a specific string in their subject and making a copy in Drafts. Some of them will be modified and Sent, in which case only the copy will remain there, some others will be manually closed (clicking the top right window `x`) and in such a case the mail will be deleted, only the copy remining. Would this understanding be a correct one? If so, I think it can be done... But your code must 'wait` until the `Close` event is triggered, which to make `True` one of the two boolean variables (for the both cases)....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next way:

1. Copy the next adapted code (instead of your code, or in a new standard module):

```
Option Explicit

Private itmevt As New CMailItemEvents
Public deleteFromDrafts As Boolean, boolContinue As Boolean

Sub TeamcenterWEBAccount()
 Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem, NewItem As Outlook.MailItem, boolDisplay As Boolean
 Dim olApp As Outlook.Application, Fldr As MAPIFolder, olNs As NameSpace

 Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
 Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
 Set Fldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDrafts)

 For Each olMail In Fldr.Items
    If InStr(olMail.Subject, "New account") > 0 Then
       On Error Resume Next  'for the case of inline response
       Set NewItem = olMail.Copy
       If Err.Number = -2147467259 Then
            Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0
            olMail.Display: boolDisplay = True
            For i = 1 To 1000: DoEvents: Next i 'just wait for the window to be displayed...
            Set NewItem = olMail.Copy
       End If
       On Error GoTo 0
        deleteFromDrafts = False: boolContinue = False 'initialize the boolean variables to wait for them in the loop
        If Not boolDisplay Then olMail.Display
        Set itmevt.itm = olMail
        
        'wait for close event to be triggered...
        Do While deleteFromDrafts = False And boolContinue = False
                DoEvents
        Loop
        
        If deleteFromDrafts Then
                If Not olMail Is Nothing Then olMail.Delete 'let only the copy...
        End If
        Exit Sub
    End If
 Next olMail
End Sub
```

2. Copy the next adapted code to replace the existing one in the used class:

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents itm As Outlook.MailItem

Private Sub itm_Close(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim blnSent As Boolean
    
    On Error GoTo Ending 'for the case of mail sending, when itm looses its reference...
        If blnSent = False Then
            itm.DeleteAfterSubmit = True
            deleteFromDrafts = True
        Else
           boolContinue = True
        End If
        Exit Sub
Ending:
    boolContinue = True
End Sub
```

Tested, but not intensively...

Please, send some feedback after testing it in your specific environment.

Comment: Works like a charm. I got multiple drafts so I changed the code. An upload will come soon.

Comment: @user19616592 OK. I am curious what was needed to be changed...

Comment: My final code has some extra code due to similar draft titles, but what I changed in order to make it work for multiple drafts was to add a variable to the sub and call that sub with the searchstring as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, iterating over all items in the folder is not really a good idea:

```
For Each olMail In Fldr.Items
    If InStr(olMail.Subject, "New account") <> 0 Then
```

Instead, let the store provider do the job for you. The `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class allows getting items that correspond to your conditions, so you could iterate over items needed. Read more about these methods in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

You may try handling the [Close](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.inspector.close(even)) event of the `Inspector` class which is fired when the inspector associated with a Microsoft Outlook item is being closed.

But I think none of them can be helpful. You need to re-design the whole solution by tracking for new items in the folder. And if new items have a custom property which indicates whether to remove the item or not you can do the additional actions. In the item-level event it is impossible to delete the source item.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. If possible it would be highly appreciated if you could elaborate on your suggested solution? Do you mean a check should be done continuously (loop)? I doubt that's what you mean.

Comment: You can handle the `ItemAdd` event on the folder and check whether the just added items is required to be removed. Or just consider using a timer where you could periodically scan for items to remove.

Answer (score 0):

My changes in module:

```
    Private itmevt As New CMailItemEvents
    Public deleteFromDrafts As Boolean, boolContinue As Boolean, boolDisplay As Boolean
    Private olMail As Outlook.MailItem, NewItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Private olApp As Outlook.Application, olNs As NameSpace, Fldr As MAPIFolder
    
    
    Sub TeamcenterWEBAccount()
        AccountOrInstallation ("Nieuw TC11 VDL ETG Teamcenter WEB account")
    End Sub
    
    Sub AccountOrInstallation(ByVal SearchStr As String)
    
    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Fldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDrafts)

    For Each olMail In Fldr.Items
        If InStr(olMail.Subject, SearchStr) > 0 Then
           On Error Resume Next  'for the case of inline response
           Set NewItem = olMail.Copy
           If Err.Number = -2147467259 Then
                Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0
                olMail.Display: boolDisplay = True
                For i = 1 To 1000: DoEvents: Next i 'just wait for the window to be displayed...
                Set NewItem = olMail.Copy
           End If
           On Error GoTo 0
            deleteFromDrafts = False: boolContinue = False 'initialize the boolean variables to wait for them in the loop
            If Not boolDisplay Then olMail.Display
            Set itmevt.itm = olMail
            
            'wait for close event to be triggered...
            Do While deleteFromDrafts = False And boolContinue = False
                    DoEvents
            Loop
            
            If deleteFromDrafts Then
                    If Not olMail Is Nothing Then olMail.Delete 'let only the copy...
            End If
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next olMail
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).